# Using OWL to assign classes from properties

Tags: alignment, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

Is it possible to represent with OWL(Web Ontology Language) something like this:
All resources at the end of a specific property are a specific class.

Example by using Vehicle Sales Ontology:

All resources at the end of `vso:height` are also a class `ex:Height` :

`ex:ModelA vso:height [ a ex:SomeRandomClass . ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [`rdfs:range`](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_range) to achieve this.

Example, consider the following OWL knowledge base (pseudo Manchester syntax):

```
ObjectProperty: has-height
    Range: Height

Class: Height

Individual: heightA

Individual: modelA
    Facts: has-height heightA
```

When a reasoner is run over it, it will deduce that the individual `heightA` has `rdf:type` `Height` (in other words `heightA a Height`).

Alternatively, a more expressive solution can be based on [existential quantifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#Property_Restrictions). See example by following the link.